# Why won't my Galaxy Tab 2 connect with WiFi or USB?

Tags: wi-fi, usb, samsung-galaxy-tab, networking, connection-issues

Whenever I try to connect to WiFi or my PC with USB, it always just says "connecting..." indefinitely.  It detects my WiFi signal, kies detects the tablet, but neither one has managed to actually complete a connection.

I've tried re-installing kies, manually adding my network, factory resetting the Tab, and running the kies connecting troubleshooter.  None of those have worked. I'm starting to think I should just return it and buy a laptop.

Comment: Why are you running the Kies connecting troubleshooter if its said "kies detects the tablet"? That's ruled out, the usb does work and detects it no? what android version are you using? Is it custom ROM?

Comment: kies does detect the tablet but it never fully connects. it says its connecting but it never actually does. i have managed to get it connected to wifi now, so at least i can use it, but i would really like to be able to connect it to my pc. also the tab doesnt show up in my computer when i connect it so i cant add files that way either. oh and its running ics 4.0.4 i think. (sorry this is my first time using an android os)